# Remove underscore and capitalize character after it

Tags: unix, command-line, replace, sed, awk

I was just wondering if there is a way to replace every underscore in every file in a folder (say .java files) and convert the next character to uppercase, like

- `getEmployee_Name` → `getEmployeeName`
- `us_employee_name` → `usEmployeeName`

And what if we had `id` and we wanted to capitalize both `I` and `D`, as in

- `us_employee_id` → `usEmployeeID`?

I haven't tried anything yet since I'm  still learning. Can I do something like `s/_/\U\1/g` in `sed` or can I use some script to do this?

Comment: If you can use Perl, it has a _CamelCase_ module: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3A%3ACamelCase

Comment: Hmmm... how do I actually call this? perl 'decamelize("Some String")' ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your suggestion `'s/_/\U\1/g'` is very close. If you have the GNU sed, then the following *should* work:

```
sed 's/_\(.\)/\U\1/g'
```

(I say *should*, because what you wish for is not always what you want.)

Comment: Note that Joseph's solution doesn't work on the default implementation of sed on MacOS. I was able to work around this by logging into a CentOS box and running there.

Answer (score 2):

Little more verbose from awk but it will work on all gnu/non-gnu Unix flavors:

```
> s='get_employee_Name'
> awk -F _ '{printf "%s", $1; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s", toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i, 2); print"";}' <<< "$s"
getEmployeeName
```

Comment: Only works for the first underscore, then strips the rest.  OP (and I) were looking for something that replaces them all.

Comment: @Ryan: I have updated my answer to work with any number of underscores now. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Perl script:

```
use String::CamelCase qw(camelize);

while (<>) {
  print camelize($_);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
files=(*.java)
for ((i=0; i<=${#files[@]}; i++ )) ; do
    file="${files[$i]}"
    awk -f r.awk "$file" > "${file}.mod"
done
```

where `r.awk` is

```
{
    str=$0
    mstr=""
    while(match(str,/_([[:alnum:]])/,a)) {
        q=substr(str,RSTART+RLENGTH,2)
        chr=a[1]
        pos=RSTART+RLENGTH
        pos2=RSTART-1
        if (length(q)==1) {
            if (match(q,/[[:alnum:]]/)) {
                chr=chr q
                pos=pos+1
            }
        }
        else if (length(q)==2) {
            if (match(q,/[[:alnum:]][[:blank:]]/)) {
                pos=pos+1
                chr=chr substr(q,1,1)
            }
        }
        mstr=(mstr substr(str,1,pos2) toupper(chr))
        str=substr(str,pos)
    }
    print (mstr str)
}
```

Given input file `file1.java`

```
getEmployee_Name getEmployee_Name
us_employee_id
    us_employee_id
asdf_asdf__
```

we get from `awk -f r.awk file1.java` :

```
getEmployeeName getEmployeeName
usEmployeeID
    usEmployeeID
asdfAsdf__
```